# Check listbox selected item value with cell value

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I got a listbox (with checkbox in it) and the list box is set to `fmMultiSelectMulti`.

What I am try to do is if any item is selected at the index then check the cell value if same then it will be copy all related data to others workbook. My lisbox is populate as below:

```
For x = 0 To 13
    'add item to listbox
    Linelistbox.AddItem "01"
    Linelistbox.AddItem "02"
    Linelistbox.AddItem "03"
    Linelistbox.AddItem "04"
    Linelistbox.AddItem "05"
    Linelistbox.AddItem "06"
    Linelistbox.AddItem "07"
    Linelistbox.AddItem "08"
    Linelistbox.AddItem "09"
    Linelistbox.AddItem "10"
    Linelistbox.AddItem "11"
    Linelistbox.AddItem "12"
    Linelistbox.AddItem "13"
    Linelistbox.AddItem "14"

    For y = 0 To Linelistbox.ListCount - 1
    Linelistbox.Selected(y) = True
    Next y

    Exit Sub
Next x
```

I have tried to achieve what I am try to by using those method.

1. ```
   For z = 0 To Me.Linelistbox.ListCount - 1
       If LineCheckBox.Selected(z) = True Then
           For i = 2 To LastRow
               Set rwSrc = SourceSheet.Rows(i)
               If rwSrc.Cells(4).Value = Fab Then
                   If rwSrc.Cells(5).Value = Linelistbox.List(z).Value Then
                       If rwSrc.Cells(6).Value = Year Then
                           If rwSrc.Cells(7).Value = WW Then
                               If rwSrc.Cells(9).Value = Test Then
                                   erow = DestSheet.Cells(DestSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                                   With DestSheet.Rows(erow)
                                       .Cells(1).Value = rwSrc.Cells(2).Value
                                       'adjust the 50 to match your actual data
                                       .Cells(2).Resize(1, 54) = rwSrc.Cells(10).Resize(1, 54).Value
                                   End With
                               End If
                           End If
                       End If
                   End If
               End If
           Next i
       End If
   Next z
   ```
2. Use Select Case

```
Dim index as integer
index = Linelistbox.ListIndex

Select Case index 
Case Is = 0
If Linelistbox.Selected(0) = True Then
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            Set rwSrc = SourceSheet.Rows(i)
            If rwSrc.Cells(4).Value = Fab Then
                If rwSrc.Cells(5).Value = "01" Then
                    If rwSrc.Cells(6).Value = Year Then
                        If rwSrc.Cells(7).Value = WW Then
                            If rwSrc.Cells(9).Value = Test Then
                                erow = DestSheet.Cells(DestSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                                With DestSheet.Rows(erow)
                                    .Cells(1).Value = rwSrc.Cells(2).Value
                                    'adjust the 50 to match your actual data
                                    .Cells(2).Resize(1, 54) = rwSrc.Cells(10).Resize(1, 54).Value
                                End With
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next i
End If

Case Is = 1
If Linelistbox.Selected(1) = True Then
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            Set rwSrc = SourceSheet.Rows(i)
            If rwSrc.Cells(4).Value = Fab Then
                If rwSrc.Cells(5).Value = "02" Then
                    If rwSrc.Cells(6).Value = Year Then
                        If rwSrc.Cells(7).Value = WW Then
                            If rwSrc.Cells(9).Value = Test Then
                                erow = DestSheet.Cells(DestSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                                With DestSheet.Rows(erow)
                                    .Cells(1).Value = rwSrc.Cells(2).Value
                                    'adjust the 50 to match your actual data
                                    .Cells(2).Resize(1, 54) = rwSrc.Cells(10).Resize(1, 54).Value
                                End With
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next i
End If
'and so on
```

By using the 1st method it got an error

> object required.

Is there anythings wrong with the code that I can fix? By using Select case method the output will display the last index selected for example if I select item at index 0 and 1, it will copy data related with index 1 only. The output should display both item related since my listbox property is multi select.

Is there any way that I can do this efficiently and pro grammatically. I have been stuck at this for a days.

I am new to vba and got so much things that I need to learn on how to working with this excel vba.

Comment: What line in your first attempt produced the "object required" error?

Comment: @TimWilliams i recently found the error just because I using ```rwSrc.Cells(5).Value = Linelistbox.List(z).Value```. I remove .value and it works fine.

Comment: Your `For x = 0 To 13` loop: this will add same items in your listbox **14** times and then select the top 14 elements.. is this what you intended? I'm presuming that's not the case...

Comment: I use ```Exit Sub``` to exit after all the item is added to the listbox and it work fine for me.

Comment: @TimWilliams I've been wondering if I using method 1 to copy paste the data, how to add the border around the paste data in the destnation sheet?

Comment: Record a macro while adding the border and that should be a good starting point.

Comment: @TimWilliams It is possible to using the recorded macro accross diffrence workbook since my SourceSheet and DestSheet is on difference workbook? I copy paste the data using button click from userform and I intend to add the border by using same method.

Comment: It's best to start a new question if you have a new requirement.